# Error on my solution to Cookie Clicker (Google Code Jam)

Tags: java

/* Below is my code for the solution of Cookie Clicker. 
I ran through the 4 cases provided by Google. Three of the cases ran well, however, when the input are decimals, the output is wrong. Can anyone to help me with this? (At first, I thought it was just a precision problem and I tried to use Big Decimal, but it did not work)
Example(Provided by Google)

Case 1 input 30.0 1.0 2.0/
Case 2 input 30.0 2.0 100.0
Case 3 input 30.50000 3.14159 1999.19990
Case 4 input 500.0 4.0 2000.0

Case #1: 1.0000000
Case #2: 39.1666667
Case #3: 63.9680013
Case #4: 526.1904762*/

My solution to Case #3
(Only this case went wrong, others were pretty good)
Please enter the value for C F and X
input :30.5000 3.14159 1999.19990
output:64.868952130833207547766505740582942962646484375*/

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class CookieClicker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        double cookie=0; // number of cookies
        double current_growth_rate=2.0;
        double new_growth_rate=0;
        double total_time=0;
        double time1=0;
        double time2=0;     

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Please enter the number of cases");
        //int numCase = input.nextInt();
        //for(int i = 1;i <= numCase;i++ ){
        System.out.println("Please enter the value for C F and X");

        double C= input.nextDouble();

        double F= input.nextDouble();

        double X= input.nextDouble(); // total required cookies



        while(cookie<X){

            time1 = X/current_growth_rate;

            //System.out.println("This is time 1 "+time1);

            time2 = ((C/current_growth_rate)+(X/(F+current_growth_rate)));

            //System.out.println("This is time 2 "+time2);

            if(time1>time2){
                // deduct C amount of cookies from the total amount of cookies(buy farm)
                cookie=cookie-C;
                // capture the time that spend on making money to buy a farm
                total_time = total_time +(C/current_growth_rate);
                //System.out.println(total_time);
                current_growth_rate=current_growth_rate+F;
                new_growth_rate= current_growth_rate+F;
            }
            cookie= cookie+current_growth_rate;
        }
        total_time=total_time+time1;
        System.out.println(new BigDecimal(total_time));
        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used double instead of BidDecimal, I have my code below quite similar as yours, I might help you to understand the issue in your code.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));
    int numberOfTest = scanner.nextInt(); 

    for(int t = 1 ; t <= numberOfTest ; t++) {
        double cokkiesRate = 2.0;
        double C_FARMCOST = scanner.nextDouble();
        double F_COKKIES_PER_SEC = scanner.nextDouble();
        double X_TARGET = scanner.nextDouble();

        double consumedTime = 0.0;

        boolean keeprun = true;

        while(keeprun) {
            if((X_TARGET - C_FARMCOST)/(cokkiesRate) 
                    < X_TARGET / (cokkiesRate + F_COKKIES_PER_SEC)){
                consumedTime = consumedTime + (X_TARGET/cokkiesRate);
                cokkiesRate+=F_COKKIES_PER_SEC;
                keeprun = false;
            }else {

                consumedTime = consumedTime + (C_FARMCOST/cokkiesRate);
                cokkiesRate+=F_COKKIES_PER_SEC;
            }
        }        
        System.out.println("Case #"+t+": "+String.format("%.7f", consumedTime));
```